# Writing a Scope containing a method - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails and any help or advise would be much appreciated

- i am trying write a scope that displays users with ratings equal or greater than 4. I am unsure why my scope is not working and your help would be much appreciated

> user.rb

```
scope :ratings_equal_and_greater_than_4, where('average_rating_final_score >= 4')

def average_rating_final_score
    if self.average_rating_score == 1.0
      1
    elsif self.average_rating_score == 2.0
      2
    elsif self.average_rating_score == 3.0
      3
    elsif self.average_rating_score == 4.0
      4
    elsif self.average_rating_score == 5.0
      5
    else
      self.average_rating_score
    end    
  end

  def average_rating_score
    ratings_total.to_f / ratings_count
  end
```

the scope works well when written like this:

```
<% if user.average_rating_final_score >= 4 %>
   # display users with ratings equal to or greater than 4 star
<% end %>
```

but i would like to write something like this in my views

```
@users.ratings_equal_and_greater_than_4
```

could one kindly advise me how to write this correctly as a scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails scopes is the AREL - a kind of ruby wrapped sql.
It's mean you can't call ruby code from SQL WHERE statement like this:

```
where('average_rating_final_score >= 4')
```

But you can define class method that will work as you want:

```
def self.ratings_equal_and_greater_than_4
  all.reject{ |record| record.average_rating_final_score < 4 }
end
```

Also you can write propper SQL query:

```
where('(`table_name.ratings_total` / `table_name.ratings_count`) >= 4')
```